# Python Multiple Inheritance - values not accessible

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have a few classes set up that hold values for an application. I'd like to import them into the same class, however, the values in the last class are being ignored. Here is a simple example.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.testA = 'A'

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.testB = 'B'

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.testA)
        print(self.testB)

test = C()
```

The above will work only if I do not include the print(self.testB) the variable in class 'B'. I'd like to access the data from Class B as well. How? Thank you.

Comment: Add `super().__init__()` to `A.__init__()` for correct initialization

Comment: If you are trying to use cooperative multiple inheritance then you need super in all the classes